# Publish and subscribe messages with MQTT in python and a heroku webpage

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, mqtt

I have two questions.
I use MQTT in python to receive messages from a heroku webpage.
I have two textboxes (value1 and value2) on my heroku webpage. I send the values with MQTT to a python script.

**This code works**:
If value1 bigger is than 10 the led is on or if value2 bigger is than 10 the led is on.

```
 def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

if(msg.topic=="/send/value1/to/led"):

  if ( int(msg.payload) > 10):

   GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)



if(msg.topic=="/send/value2/to/led"):

  if ( int(msg.payload) > 10):

   GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
```

*My first question.*
I want this: if the sum of value1 and value2 bigger is than 10 than the led is on.
**This code doesn't work.**

```
   **def on_message(client, userdata, msg):**


if(msg.topic=="/send/value1/to/led"):

  value1 = int(msg.payload)


     if(msg.topic=="/send/value2/to/led"):

         value2 = int(msg.payload)

         if ((value1 + value2) > 10):
            GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Can someone help me?

*My second question.*
I have another heroku webpage where I try receive messages.
I type this: `import mysql.connector as mc`
On my heroku webpage I get this error: **No module named mysql.connector**. I use also a requirements.txt file.

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Python is white space sensitive, please edit your question so all the code is correctly indented so we can be sure of what your intentions are.

Comment: Also your 2 questions don't actually look to be all that related, you may do better splitting them and tagging them appropriately.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the first case, or what happens?

Comment: I want this: I send two values (from two texboxes from a heroku webpage) with mqtt. If the sum of this two texboxes is bigger than 10, then a led needs go on.

Comment: Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit difficult to answer given you are asking two different questions, so I will only address the first and encourage you to split the second one off.

Looking at your code I think that the problem has to do with the way that you are nesting the statements. I think the problem is that the on_message callback receives a single message each time it is called so the second condition can never be met. But given that I'm not sure if your whitespace is accurate or not it is unclear.

However, I would avoid using if statements that way to begin with and simply use the message_callback_add function in the library (I'm assuming you are using the Paho client here) to call two separate functions and then pass variables out of them using a global. Then process those two variables using a while loop. Here is the documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#callbacks . This will provide you with a far cleaner approach that should be easy enough to get working.

Here is some example code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe('led/#')

def value_one(client, userdata, message):
    global value1
    value1 = int(message.payload)

def value_two(client, userdata, message):
    global value2
    value2 = int(message.payload)


MQTT_BROKER = []
client = mqtt.Client(client_id='whatever')
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.message_callback_add('led/value_one', value_one)
client.message_callback_add('led/value_two', value_two)
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER)
client.loop_start()

while True:
    if value1 + value2 > 10:
        #Do Something
        pass
    time.sleep(30)
```

I did that from memory, so there may be errors but it illustrates the basic principle of using topic based callbacks, global variables, and a while loop to process the results.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Yes I use paho client. Can you give me an example code how I can do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I added some code. It isn't complete but it should illustrate the basic programming flow. Incidentally you could also do away with the while loop by putting the processing code directly into one of the callbacks but I think this approach is easier to understand.

Also note that is considered bad practice to start an MQTT topic with a / as it creates an unnecessary layer of topics and leads to confusion. (Not a big deal but worth noting.)

Comment: No problem, if it solved the issue you were having I would recommend accepting the answer and then spinning off your second question into a separate thread.